# convert numpy array to string with delimiter and save to txt file

Tags: python, string, numpy

I'm trying to convert numpy array to string with delimiter and save it to txt file.

I tried:

```
im = np.reshape(gray, (1,n_row*n_col))
res_str= " ".join(map(str, im))
```

it seems to work ok when I test it in console, but when I save it to file it become string with ellipsis something like

> [[48 49 45 ..., 47 46 46]]

code:

```
with open('file.txt', "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(np.array_str(im)) #don't work
    #res_str= " ".join(map(str, im))
    #myfile.write(str(res_str))      #also don't work
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1,100))
np.savetxt('data.csv',data,delimiter=',',fmt='%d')     #numpy savetxt
```

**and the output:**

[data.csv]

```
70,53,95,60,91,...
```

**You can also define other formats:**

```
fmt='"%d"'
```

**which results in:**

```
"70","53","95","60","91",...
```

**You can find more about numpy.savetxt at** [{here}](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html).

Comment: It works, but I need to add str(int)+ " | " to the begining of the string also.

Comment: You can add `header='str(int)+ " | "'` and it will do what you want. I.e., `np.savetxt('data.csv',data,delimiter=',',fmt='%d',header='str(int)+ " | "')`.

Comment: Using header, header is not on the same line as digits and appear with comment #.

Comment: also I need to append string to file, savetxt seems can't do this.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to convert an (multidimensional) array to string is to use [tolist()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> result = str(a.tolist())
>>> result
'[[1, 2], [3, 4]]'
```

This `result` you could save to various file types. And if you want to restore the numpy array from this `result` string. You could use [ast.literal_eval()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
>>> import ast
>>> restored_a = np.array(ast.literal_eval('[[1, 2], [3, 4]]'))
>>> restored_a
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```